# How do I get my browser extension to redirect the website I want it to?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm coding my own browser extension and I would like to redirect https://www.roblox.com/ to https://www.google.com/. I have all of the code set up I just need this small problem fixed.

My manifest.json is:

[Manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mcW5.png)

My background.js is:
[Background.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjTEF.png)

My popup.js is:
[Popup.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azZSO.png)

My popup.html is:
[Popup.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3c17.png)

I think there is something wrong in the background.js with line 3 and 10. I don't think I specified the websites correctly. Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: All your codes are images. Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) You can format code as text, see: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).